# Python. Django test weird behavior. PDB

Tags: python, django, pdb

So, I have a test that looks like this:

```
 for retailer in Retailer.objects.all():
    retailer_categories = retailer.categories.all()
    empty_categories = []
    not_empty_categories = []
    for category in retailer_categories:
        if StockItem.objects.filter(retailer=retailer, product__category=category).exists():
            not_empty_categories.append(category.name)
        else:
            empty_categories.append(category.name)
    response = self.client.get(reverse("misuper:retailer_categories", kwargs={"id": retailer.id}))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    response_category_names = [c["name"] for c in response.json()]
    for category_name in response_category_names:
        pdb.set_trace()  # HERE
        self.assertEqual(category_name in not_empty_categories, True, "%s not in %s" % (category_name, not_empty_categories))  # THIS TEST
```

The weird part is that if I run the test and at the breakpoint I just hit `c` (continue), it fails the test:

> /home/alejandro/Proyectos/misuper_env/misuper_project/app/misuper/tests.py(1162)test_retailers_categories()
>
> -> pdb.set_trace()
>
> (Pdb) c
>
> FAIL ...
>
> AssertionError: Bebidas not in []

But if in the breakpoint I write `category_name` and `response_category_names` just to print them, the test passes correctly.

> (Pdb) category_name
>
> u'Bebidas'
>
> (Pdb) response_category_names
>
> [u'Bebidas']
>
> (Pdb) c
>
> ok

Why??

Comment: It's a bit bizarre to use `assertEqual(condition, True)`; why not just `assertTrue(condition)`?

Answer (score 0):

The test has `category_name in not_empty_categories`, not `response_category_names`. I believe the `not_empty_categories` here is empty.